# 502 Bad Gateway - Nginx + Laravel + Nuxt 3

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, nuxt3

I've been facing this issue for quite time, My Frontend is using Nuxt 3 and my api is using Laravel 9, they are both on same server. My issue is that after successful login, returns 502 Bad Gateway but when I reload the browser, it works fine.

Nuxt 3 nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name maindomain.com;
    
    location / {


        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header  Connection "keep-alive";
        proxy_connect_timeout            300s;
        proxy_send_timeout               300s;
        proxy_read_timeout               300s;
        send_timeout                     300s;
    }

   
}
```

Laravel API Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.maindomain.com;
    root /var/www/html/maindomain/backend/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions is very much appreciated!

Comment: seems like a race condition between Nuxt and Laravel starting causing the issue of 502

Comment: I also used same approach same config with other project and it works normally fine. It just this project having an issue.

Comment: check the start time for both nuxt and laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue by updating my frontend nginx config

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

 upstream frontend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
 }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name maindomain.com;
    #root /var/www/html/maindomain;


    location / {


        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header  Connection "keep-alive";
        proxy_connect_timeout            300s;
        proxy_send_timeout               300s;
        proxy_read_timeout               300s;
}
```

and after changes, I restarted my AWS instance and it works.
Restarting my nginx does not help, that is why I restart my instance.